# How to disable multiple radiobuttons in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

This part of my program allows user to choose numbers from 1 to 5 and provide the sum of all numbers chosen. I want to disable the radio buttons when the sum reaches 30. How can I do that?

```
total_choices = [("1"),
                 ("2"),
                 ("3"),
                 ("4"),
                 ("5")]
var = tk.IntVar()
var.set(0)  

sum = 0
def Calculator():
    global sum
    num = var.get()
    sum = sum + num
    if sum>30
       # Grey out all the radio buttons

for val, choice in enumerate(total_choices):
    tk.Radiobutton(root,
                   text=choice,
                   indicatoron = 0,
                   width = 10,
                   variable=var,
                   command=Calculator,
                   value=val).place(x=val*100,y=180)
```

Comment: Keep a reference to each radiobutton, and set the state to `"disabled"` for each.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same in another program where I have many buttons. I would have to individually refer them all which would be cumbersome. Is there any way I can use a 1D array to change all their states?
For eg,
     btn[num].config(state=DISABLED)

When I try it, it give me a 'Nonetype' error

Comment: Can you use a 1D array? Of course. There's nothing special about a widget object. It's no different than an object of any other type. As for the NoneType error, that problem has been asked about and answered about 1000 times on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable radio buttons by looking them up from the children list of their parents:

```
try:                        # In order to be able to import tkinter for
    import tkinter as tk    # either in python 2 or in python 3
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk


def disable_multiple_radiobuttons():
    global total
    print(repr(sum_label['text']))
    total += var.get()
    sum_label['text'] = total
    if total >= 30:
        for child in root.winfo_children():
            if child.winfo_class() == 'Radiobutton':
                child['state'] = 'disabled'


root = tk.Tk()
var = tk.IntVar(value=1)
total = 0
sum_label = tk.Label(root, text=total)
sum_label.pack()
for i in range(1, 6):
    tk.Radiobutton(root, text=i, variable=var, value=i,
        command=disable_multiple_radiobuttons).pack()
tk.mainloop()
```

or you can put them in a collection type and simply disable them at ease:

```
try:                        # In order to be able to import tkinter for
    import tkinter as tk    # either in python 2 or in python 3
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk


def on_rb_press():
    sum_label['text'] += var.get()
    if sum_label['text'] >= 30:
        for key in radiobuttons:
            radiobuttons[key]['state'] = 'disabled'


root = tk.Tk()
sum_label = tk.Label(root, text=0)
sum_label.pack()
radiobuttons = dict()
var = tk.IntVar(value=1)
for i in range(1, 6):
    radiobuttons[i] = tk.Radiobutton(root, text=i, variable=var,
                                                value=i, command=on_rb_press)
    radiobuttons[i].pack()
tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: The first option worked. The second option gave me the following error:
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1532, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Python27/totaler.py", line 15, in on_rb_press
    radiobuttons[key]['state'] = "DISABLED"
TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment

Answer (score 0):

I would store all the radio buttons in a list, then disable every buttons when you reach 30, as seen below :

```
total_choices = [("1"),
                 ("2"),
                 ("3"),
                 ("4"),
                 ("5")]
var = tk.IntVar()
var.set(0)  

sum = 0
def Calculator():
    global sum
    global buttons
    num = var.get()
    sum = sum + num
    if sum>30
       # Grey out all the radio buttons
        for b in buttons:
            b.config(state=disabled)

global buttons
buttons = list()
for val, choice in enumerate(total_choices):
    buttons.append(tk.Radiobutton(root,
        text=choice,
        indicatoron = 0,
        width = 10,
        variable=var,
        command=Calculator,
        value=val))
    buttons[-1].place(x=val*100,y=180))
```

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1532, in __call__
        return self.func(*args)
      File "C:/Python27/totaler.py", line 23, in Calculator
        b.config(state=disabled)
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'config'

Same error messages again. Btw, I'm using Python 2.7.9. I can't figure out if the method is wrong or it's a syntax error because of a different version