# how to disable the other two radiobuttons which bind to its own frame in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button, disable

I am designing a GUI with tkinter. There are three radio-buttons bind to each individual frame. Is it a way to disable the other two radio-buttons by clicking one of them? Or even better to disable the other two frame[image]

I am not able to achieve this feature. Below is part of the code. Please let me know if you need more information. Thanks

```py
root = Tk()
root.title("MyApp")   

f1 = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
f1.grid(row=0, sticky=(W, E, N, S))
Label(f1, text = "Welcome to My App!", font=("Times New Roman", 20)).grid(column=3, row=1, sticky='EW')  


root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

option = StringVar()

topframe=ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12", relief = GROOVE, borderwidth = 10)
topframe.grid(row=1, sticky=(W, E, N, S))

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12",  relief = GROOVE, borderwidth = 10)
mainframe.grid(row=2, sticky=(W, E, N, S))

bottomframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12", relief = GROOVE, borderwidth = 10)
bottomframe.grid(row=3, sticky=(W, E, N, S))

paraframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12" , relief = GROOVE, borderwidth = 10)
paraframe.grid(row=4, sticky=(W, E, N, S))



rb1 = Radiobutton(topframe, text="Select Files", value="files", var=option)
rb1.grid(column=0, columnspan=2, row=0, sticky=W)

rb2 = Radiobutton(mainframe, text="Select a Directory", value="directory", var=option)
rb2.grid(column=0,columnspan=2, row=0,sticky=W)

rb3 = Radiobutton(bottomframe, text="Paste a JSON File", value="json", var=option)
rb3.grid(column=0,columnspan=2, row=0,sticky=W)

# function to gray out
def greyOutNotTop():
    if option.get() == "files":
        rb2.config(state='disable')
        rb3.config(state='disable')

def greyOutNotMain():
    if option.get() == "directory":
        rb1.config(state='disable')
        rb3.config(state='disable')
def greyOutNotBottom():
    if option.get() == "json":
        rb1.config(state='disable')
        rb2.config(state='disable')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49061602/how-to-disable-multiple-radiobuttons-in-python

Comment: I tried to disable the children of the other two frames. for example, If I select rb1, then disable all children of mainframe and bottomframe.   Try to call the function from each Label, Entry and button associated with these two frames. Unfortunately, I failed to make them work.                             
    for child in mainframe.winfo_children():
             child.config (state =disabled)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, like this:

```
def greyOutNotTop():
    rb2.config(state='disable')
    rb3.config(state='disable')

rb1 = Radiobutton(topframe, text="Select Files", value="files", var=option, command =greyOutNotTop)
rb1.grid(column=0, columnspan=2, row=0, sticky=W)
```

But there's a huge problem with that. If you disable the other 2 radiobuttons, the user can't click on them anymore. So with the first click they are committed.

You need to rethink your design. I think a ttk.Notebook would make a lot more sense here.

Comment: I plan to add another widget which can enable(reset) all three radio-button. This is my plan and haven't work on it yet.